# wandb.init() under offline failed on server, but success on my PC, how to fix on server?

Tags: wandb

wandb.init() under offline failed on server, but success on my PC.
Why and how to fix problem on server?

Here are log, server info, my PC info, code.

log:
wandb: Currently logged in as: myName. Use `wandb login --relogin` to force relogin
Problem at: <stdin> 1 <module>t()...
wandb: ERROR Run initialization has timed out after 120.0 sec.
wandb: ERROR Please refer to the documentation for additional information: https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/tracking-faq#initstarterror-error-communicating-with-wandb-process-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/wxx/.conda/envs/wxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/sdk/wandb_init.py", line 1195, in init
raise e
File "/home/wxx/.conda/envs/wxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/sdk/wandb_init.py", line 1176, in init
run = wi.init()
File "/home/wxx/.conda/envs/wxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wandb/sdk/wandb_init.py", line 785, in init
raise error
wandb.errors.CommError: Run initialization has timed out after 120.0 sec.

server:
ubuntu:
Linux version 6.5.0-14-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-110) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2
python 3.8.0
wandb 0.16.4

my PC:
windows 10
python 3.8.0
wandb 0.16.4

code:

```
import wandb 
import os os.environ["WANDB_API_KEY"] = 'my key' 
os.environ["WANDB_MODE"] = "offline" 
wandb.init()
```

Here are my try 1 2 3 4:

my try 1:

```
os.environ["WANDB_API_KEY"] = 'my key' 
os.environ["WANDB_MODE"] = "offline" 
wandb.init()
```

my try 2:

```
wandb.init(settings=wandb.Settings(start_method="thread"))
```

my try 3:

```
wandb.init(settings=wandb.Settings(start_method="fork"))
```

my try 4:

```
wandb.init()
```

all failed on server, the failed logs are the same.
hope to run initialization on server success! Thanks!